# Unity Canvas Buttons gets tiny when Build

Tags: unity3d-2dtools, unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I am working with Unity 5, and when I add Canvas Button the button get smaller
this is how it looks like before build
Before Build to an Apk
[image: Before]

and after build on my Lg g3:
[image: After]

Comment: what are your canvas settings?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/67da658138f2b296084b6c87acaa7381 - canvas

Comment: https://gyazo.com/ce745f52d141ac64df9b726ac6b1dacf - Button(Play)

Comment: You should include those screenshots into your question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As seen on your screenshots, the  button has a fixed size in pixels. and your mobile screen probably has a higher screen resolution.

Set the Canvas Scaler to something other than 
*Constant Pixel Size* as this *Makes UI elements retain the same size in pixels regardless of screen size.*

*scale with screensize* would in this case be more fitting. As it *Makes UI elements bigger the bigger the screen is.*

as per [Unity Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html)